# React Hook inside constant

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add hook inside `routes` and after that I wanna import it inside **App.js** but I am getting error `React Hook "useAuth" cannot be called at the top level.` I am beginner I think I have to use component for it but I'm not sure how to import `routes` constant from component.

**App.js**

```
import routes from "./routes";
console.log(routes);
```

**route.js**

```
import { useAuth } from "./hooks/useAuth";
const { isAuthed } = useAuth();

const routes = [
  {
    exact: true,
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: pages.Home,
    permissions: isAuthed(),
  },
];

export default routes;
```

Comment: You are correct, all hooks must be used inside components. If you're trying to implement protected routes then this is not the way to go about it - google will help there.

Comment: You can create a component, say `PrivateRoute` which would check for authentication. See the [example](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow). You can use your hook `useAuth` in that `PrivateRoute` component.

Comment: @Ajeet Shah that's what I am doing but I don't want to check it on all of private components

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

First you can import your necessary dependency in your component like following:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignInPhase from 'screens/SignIn';
import PrivacyPolicy from 'screens/TermsAndPrivacy';
```

Then you might have multiple routes and from all these routes you might have protected routes which needed authentication. For authenticated you can write a function and if you have token based authentication then you can validate based on this token.

```
const Routes = () => {
    return (
        <DesktopWrapper>
             <Switch>
                  <PrivateRoute path={PRIVACY_POLICY}>
                        <PrivacyPolicy />
                   </PrivateRoute>
                   <Route exact path={SIGN_IN}>
                         <SignInPhase />
                   </Route>
              </Switch>
        </DesktopWrapper>
    );
};
```

Following is the protected route function that you used in **Routes**

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
    const access_token = store.get('access_token');

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={({ location }) =>
                access_token ? (
                    children
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: SIGN_IN,
                            state: { from: location },
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
}

export default Routes;
```

Comment: Well that's not an answer on my question, this example what you've posted I already have inside my code but when I am creating list of my routes inside an array then I am having an issue with adding hook. (goal is to make PrivateRoute that has different permision, based on key)